# ASP.NET MVC2 DataAnnotations Minimum length

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, data-annotations, minimum

Because I'm not using .net 4 I can't use StringLength.MinimumLength property. What is alternative? I suppose I should write regular expression:

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression("", ErrorMessage = "Minimum 3 characters")]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

Thanks,
Ile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.tsjensen.com/blog/CommentView,guid,904052d4-8ee0-47b5-bacb-eb1788137233.aspx

Comment: Thanks. The regular expression will just do the work. I don't understand why did the author of the blog decide to use the second solution which is requiring a lot of code comparing to one line of regular expression :) Clunky or not clunky it's one line of code :)

Comment: As the author of the blog post, I can tell you that, IMHO, any Regex is clunky compared to a more expressive, readable chunk of code like the MinStringLength attribute. But the real purpose for posting the blog entry was not to demonstrate the superiority of one approach over another but to provide an example for myself and others on how to write a custom validation attribute. (I'm responding to this because I'm getting regular visitors to my blog from this link, so thanks, Raj.)